# Probability of their product divisibility

Tags: probability

Two whole numbers are randomly selected and multiplied . Consider two events E1 and E2 defined as

$E_1$ : Their product is divisible by 5

$E_2$ : Unit's place in their product is 5 .

Then I know $P(E_1\mid E_2)=1$

and according to me $P(E_2\mid E_1)=\frac12$

but the answer is given as $P(E_2\mid E_1)=\frac14$.

how ?

Comment: Well....I expect they mean that "since you need both numbers to be odd the probability is $\frac 12\times \frac 12=\frac 14$".

Comment: Note:  at a minimum the problem should specify what "randomly selected" means.  There is, of course, no uniform distribution on an infinite set.

Comment: What is "/"? Does that mean "given that" ?

Comment: @zoli yes conditional probability

Comment: Maybe they think something like "if one of the selected numbers is $0$, then the product is zero". So having $0$ at the end of their product is more likely than $5$. But still, I don't really get what "randomly selected" numbers mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I absolutely don't like this question, because without specifying what "randomly selected" means - it's nonsense problem.

But still, this is how they get this answer:

> What does $E_1$ event consists of?

It consists of the: $E_1=\{\{0,0\}, \{0,1\}, \{0,2\}, \dots , \{0,n\}, \dots , \{5,1\}, \{5,2\}, \dots\, \{5,n\}, \dots\}$

So, one of the selected numbers should be $5$ or $0$. And they assume that this is equally likely to select $0$ or $5$.

If we selected $0$ the product is zero, and of course unit's digit is $0$. Let's say that probability of $$P\{\{n\in\mathbb{N} : \{0,n\} \in E_1\}|E_1\}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

The other case: if one of the numbers is $5$, then we have two possibilities for their product to be with last digit $0$ or $5$, which depends on the second selected number. And the author supposed this is also equally likely to select even or odd second number. Then $$P\{\{n\in \mathbb{N}: \{5,2n-1\}\in E_1\}| E_1\}=\frac{1}{4}=P\{\{n\in \mathbb{N}: \{5,2n\}\in E_1\}| E_1\}.$$

And now: $$E_1=\{n\in \mathbb{N}: \{0,n\} \in E_1\} \cup \{n\in \mathbb{N}: \{5,2n\}\in E_1\} \cup E_2$$

where $E_2 = \{n\in \mathbb{N}: \{5,2n-1\}\in E_1\}.$

Hence the answer $P\{E_2|E_1\}=\frac{1}{4}.$